# Positioning full width header

Tags: html, css, header

Positioning full width header. I would like it to come out something like this. http://meem.co.vu/

Div:

```
<div id="shell"> 

<div class="img"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ydsgqx5/f28mqvumo/waterfall-nature-wallpaper.png" width="448" height="336" alt="" /></div> 
<div id="msg"></div> 

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#shell { margin:0; 
padding:30px; 
width:600px; 
height:400px; 
background:#eee; }
div.img { width:360px; 
height:280px; 
overflow:hidden; 
margin:auto; 
}
#banner {
width: 960px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto 30px;
overflow:hidden;
float: left;
}
#banner img {
left: 0;
top: 0;
position:absolute;
}
```

Other Links: http://jsfiddle.net/BeCF9/55/

I can't seem to get the image across the screen to take up the whole page.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try
`#banner img { left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; position: absolute; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BeCF9/58/

```
#shell { margin:0; background:#eee; }
div.img { width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:auto; border:1px solid #333; }
```

check the screenshot where set div.img to 100% also override the img width to 100%.

Hope the below screenshot look is like what you want
[image]

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. There's still a gap. http://static.tumblr.com/ydsgqx5/K94mqvx99/1a5afd57b54401bf3ee8351b0372d5e6.png

Comment: is your website hosted public..so i can have a look and find the exact rson

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and you can see I might need to make the image bigger because it's not taking up the whole screen. Mind if you take another look? Is there possibly another way to make the image fit the screen instead of me re-sizing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am the owner of meem.co.vu!

First of all, I am so elated that you appreciated the design of my header. As I am no longer using the particular site layout you're referencing, people might not get what you're trying to ask.

What I did to get my header to full size on the screen was `width: 100%;` in the CSS. To get the background to also stay full size, I added `background-size: cover;` to the CSS. I hope this helps. :)